# SELECT INTO along with CASES and a JOIN to create a new table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a new table from the results column created with END AS along with an existing id column.  The results of my query are in the first table.  I want to create a new table that looks like the second one.  I have tried using SELECT INTO many different ways, but I can't get it to even create a new table from the results.

```
SELECT table1."id", table1.val, table2.val,
CASE WHEN table2.val IS NOT null AND table2.val != 'N' THEN table2.val
    WHEN table2.val = 'N' THEN null 
    WHEN table1.val = 'N' THEN null
ELSE table1.val
END AS results
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2."id" = table1."id"

+----+-----+--------+---------+
| id | val |  val   | results |
+----+-----+--------+---------+
|  1 | A   | N      | [null]  |
|  2 | A   | B      | B       |
|  3 | N   | [null] | [null]  |
|  5 | A   | [null] | A       |
|  8 | A   | B      | B       |
|  9 | N   | B      | B       |
| 10 | N   | N      | [null]  |
+----+-----+--------+---------+

+----+---------+
| id | results |
+----+---------+
|  1 | [null]  |
|  2 | B       |
|  3 | [null]  |
|  5 | A       |
|  8 | B       |
|  9 | B       |
| 10 | [null]  |
+----+---------+
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?  In standard SQL (which the tag `sql` refers to) a new table based on a select is created using `create table ... as select ...` not with `select .. into`

Comment: pgAdmin.  Kapil's answer does what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: pgAdmin is not a DBMS. But as it can only connect to a Postgres database is safe to assume that you are using Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table1."id",
CASE WHEN table2.val IS NOT null AND table2.val != 'N' THEN table2.val
WHEN table2.val = 'N' THEN null 
WHEN table1.val = 'N' THEN null
ELSE table1.val
END AS results INTO New_Table
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2."id" = table1."id"
```

Comment: @kertigen: Using `select into` to create a new table is discouraged in Postgres. It's better to use the standard `create table as` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that out. Will that work with most DBMS or is it more for Postgres?